# Integrating Qt GUI code into C#

Tags: c#, qt, com, activex, qyoto

I have to develop a plug-in for an external program using C#.
I am an experienced Qt/C++ programmer and the core of the plug-in is programmed in C++.

My first idea was to program GUI in C#, which write settings to a text file and then call the core C++ code, as an external process, with this textfile as an input.

However I also noticed that there is something called the QAxServer Module in Qt that should make it possible to run Qt/C++ GUI code from C# (trough ActiveX).
I experimented a bit with this and it seemed a bit "shaky".

Do you have any experiences with this you could share?

Answer (score 2):

I would look at writing a C++/CLI (i.e. Managed C++) shim to launch your plug-in and be the bridge between it and the main application.

This will allow you to call into (or be called from) the C# application on one side and talk native C++ on the other.

Answer (score 1):

http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto

Qyoto seems to be the most active Qt binding for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the "[QT for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/qt4dotnet/)" project.